# Active Campaign API Error - Use Web Interface Error

Tags: api, activecampaign

I just tried running the api to send a campaign message but I got the following error

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<campaign_ajax_send>
    <result_code>0</result_code>
    <result_message>Please send this campaign through the web interface to continue.</result_message>
    <result_output>xml</result_output>
</campaign_ajax_send>
```

Any help please?

Comment: got any solutions for this yet?